# Prestashop 1.7 Changing Main Nav

Tags: themes, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I want to change my theme Nav to a the default classic Prestashop theme or any horizontal menu. I changed all the menu content but still can't find what is missing.

[image]

I want my nav to be simple and horizontal like this:

[image]

Comment: you need a free lancer I think

Comment: @Wolfack i did some css changes, and even replaced the style with the classic nav docs but still can't find a method,do u have any idea !?

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve your issue yet? Below is an image of what I am setting up (slightly redacted per owner request). Let me know if you want me to dig into what I did. I made the Menu Position change early on in the styling (over 6 months ago) and don't have an installed 'demo' Classic site to compare against.

[image: My Current Header with Menu]

I have my 'Main Menu' hooked to displayTop. If that is not the key to getting you started, then I can dig into my CSS changes when I have a moment.

Comment: Thank you very much sir yes i did change the hook but there still problem, but lucky for me the client don't want it on top .

Comment: But i will be glad sir to learn from you from how you solved it, have a good day

Comment: I installed a fresh, default version of PS 1.7.2.4 (since I am going to upgrade the shop from v1.7.1.2 to v1.7.2.4 and I know some of my styling will break since PS fixed some Class Typos).  The below image is what I get get on a default install. It appears to be styled the way you want. What version of PS are you on? Unless PS changed the behavior of the Header/Top between versions, I am guessing something else in your coding overrode the default styling.

Hmmm, I have to figure out how to insert an image in a comment. However, it looks identical to what you wanted.